# embed snipe message displays user id instead of the username discord bot python

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

My discord snipe feature but functions quite well however whenever it sends the embed of the deleted message, it displays the id number of the user who deleted the message instead of showing the actual username

```
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):

    global snipe_message_content
    global snipe_message_author
    global snipe_message_id

    snipe_message_content = message.content
    snipe_message_author = message.author.id
    snipe_message_id = message.id

    embed = discord.Embed(description=f"{snipe_message_content}")
    embed.set_author(name= f"<@{snipe_message_author}>")
    channel = client.get_channel(795726497922809947)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You assigned the author ID not the author name to `snipe_message_author`

```py
snipe_message_author = message.author.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise you could use `str(message.author)` which gives you the name#tag.
But I don't recommend that way. I'm using it myself because it is shorter than `message.author.name + "#" + message.author.discriminator` But yeah.